# How to add correctly two modules in koin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, koin

I am developing a news app and I want to add two modules in application class but I am getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.di.application.SportNewsApplication: org.koin.core.error.DefinitionOverrideException: Already existing definition or try to override an existing one: [type:Single,primary_type:'yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.internet.SportNewsInterface']
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5971)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:206)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1700)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
Caused by: org.koin.core.error.DefinitionOverrideException: Already existing definition or try to override an existing one: [type:Single,primary_type:'yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.internet.SportNewsInterface']
 at org.koin.core.registry.BeanRegistry.addDefinition(BeanRegistry.kt:144)
 at org.koin.core.registry.BeanRegistry.saveDefinition(BeanRegistry.kt:101)
 at org.koin.core.registry.BeanRegistry.saveDefinitions(BeanRegistry.kt:71)
 at org.koin.core.registry.BeanRegistry.loadModules(BeanRegistry.kt:49)
 at org.koin.core.KoinApplication.loadModulesAndScopes(KoinApplication.kt:66)
 at org.koin.core.KoinApplication.modules(KoinApplication.kt:60)
 at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.di.application.SportNewsApplication$onCreate$1.invoke(SportNewsApplication.kt:19)
 at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.di.application.SportNewsApplication$onCreate$1.invoke(SportNewsApplication.kt:11)
 at org.koin.core.context.GlobalContextKt.startKoin(GlobalContext.kt:72)
 at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.di.application.SportNewsApplication.onCreate(SportNewsApplication.kt:16)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5966)
 ... 8 more
```

below SportNewsApplication.kt class

```
class SportNewsApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // Adding Koin modules to our application
        startKoin {

          //  androidContext(this@SportNewsApplication)
            modules(
            listOf(appModules, bbcModules))

        }
    }
}
```

below appModules.kt

```
const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"

val appModules = module {
    // The Retrofit service using our custom HTTP client instance as a singleton
    single {
        createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = BASE_URL
        )
    }
    // Tells Koin how to create an instance of CatRepository
    factory<NewsRepository> { (NewsRepositoryImpl(sportsNewsApi = get())) }
    // Specific viewModel pattern to tell Koin how to build MainViewModel
    viewModel { MainViewModel(newsRepository = get()) }
}

/* Returns a custom OkHttpClient instance with interceptor. Used for building Retrofit service */
fun createHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    client.readTimeout(5 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return client.addInterceptor {
        val original = it.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        val request = requestBuilder.method(original.method, original.body).build()
        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(request)
    }.build()
}

/* function to build our Retrofit service */
inline fun <reified T> createWebService(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    factory: CallAdapter.Factory, baseUrl: String
): T {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(factory)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
}
```

below bbcModules.kt

```
const val base_url = "https://newsapi.org/"

val bbcModules = module {
    // The Retrofit service using our custom HTTP client instance as a singleton
    single {
        createBBCWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createBBCHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = base_url
        )
    }
    // Tells Koin how to create an instance of CatRepository
    factory<BBCRepository> { (BBCRepositoryImpl(bbcsportNewsApi = get())) }
    // Specific viewModel pattern to tell Koin how to build MainViewModel
    viewModel { BBCSportViewModel(bbcRepository = get()) }
}

/* Returns a custom OkHttpClient instance with interceptor. Used for building Retrofit service */
fun createBBCHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    client.readTimeout(5 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return client.addInterceptor {
        val original = it.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        val request = requestBuilder.method(original.method, original.body).build()
        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(request)
    }.build()
}

/* function to build our Retrofit service */
inline fun <reified T> createBBCWebService(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    factory: CallAdapter.Factory, baseUrl: String
): T {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(factory)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
}
```

what I have tried

1.clean rebuild and invalidate cache restart and other StackOverflow answers 
it did not solve my problem.

2. I have followed following link https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/420 as well

I want to know what I have to do in order to solve the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you try to create two instances of OkHttpClient in separate modules. You can use override parametr for a module  for override one instance by other 
`(module(override = true))`
but in this case it is incorrect. You must have tow different instances OkHttpClient. For this, you can use named instance

```
single<OkHttpClient>(named("WebService")) {
        createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = BASE_URL
        )
    }
```

and

```
single<OkHttpClient>(named("BBCWebService")) {
        createBBCWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createBBCHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = base_url
        )
    }
```

If need inject specific client need to use

```
SomeClassNeedDependency(get(named("WebService")))
```

[More information](https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/definitions?id=definition-naming-amp-default-bindings)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `named`. Here is a [doc](https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/definitions?id=definition-naming-default-bindings)

below appModules.kt

```kotlin
single(named("appModules")) {
        createBBCWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createBBCHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = base_url
        )
    }

factory<NewsRepository> { (NewsRepositoryImpl(sportsNewsApi = get(named("appModules")))) }
```

below bbcModules.kt

```kotlin
single(named("bbcModules")) {
        createBBCWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createBBCHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = base_url
        )
    }

    factory<BBCRepository> { (BBCRepositoryImpl(bbcsportNewsApi = get(named("bbcModules")))) }
```